# Setting starting value for Google Line Chart dynamically and redrawing chart

Tags: forms, dynamic, google-visualization, linechart

I am using the code below to generate a line chart for a projected financial balance.  Data is generated from information in a MySQL database.  What I would like to be able to do is to have a form with an input field on the page that allows the user to set the starting balance dynamically once the page is loaded, such that the chart is redrawn with the correct starting balance, but I can't work out how to do this:

```
$rows = array();
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Amount', 'type' => 'number')
);

[code to generate data goes here - i.e. calculating a balance for each date in the chart]

    $balance = $balance - $monthly - $weekly + $session_total;
    $temp = array();

    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $date_display); 
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $balance); 
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
//echo $jsonTable;
?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
                                                    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({fractionDigits:2,prefix:'\u00A3'});
      formatter.format(data, 1);
      var options = {
          pointSize: 5,
          legend: 'none',
          hAxis: { showTextEvery:31 },
          series: {0:{color:'2E838F',lineWidth:2}},
          chartArea: {left:50,width:"95%",height:"80%"},
          backgroundColor: '#F7FBFC',
          height: 400
        };
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      //do not forget to check ur div ID
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>

      <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Just wanted to clarify that what you want is for the user to be able to insert a single new value at the beginning of the data set? and re-draw the line... The value they supply shouldn't affect anything after it?

Comment: @cchana Thanks for your message.  The user enters the starting balance and then the rest of the points on the graph are calculated using values in a MySQL database. So the value the user enters will of course affect the whole chart as the balance carries from one item to the next.  But essentially the value the user enters just needs to set the variable $balance for the first entry on the graph. I hope this is clearer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully there's a fairly simple way to refresh the chart when new data is available. It requires a small change to your PHP and a few JavaScript tweaks.

The nice thing about using Google Charts is that you can just re-draw them by calling `drawChart()` again, you just need to be able to modify the data before you do it.

The change I would make the PHP would be to store the original value, so that when you want to change the value according to the user's input you can always have something to refer back to:

```
// display the date
$temp[] = array('v' => (string) $date_display);
// the data used by the chart
$temp[] = array('v' => (string) $balance);
// the original value
$temp[] = array('v' => (string) $balance);
```

I would also make the table data global rather than drawing it directly into the function, this way you can change it and refresh the chart quite easily.

```
var table = <?php echo $jsonTable; ?>;

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(table);
    ......
}
```

I tested this with a basic form that looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" id="balance1" />
    <input type="text" id="balance2" />
    <button onclick="return refreshChart()">Go</button>
</form>
```

Clicking on the button cancels the default action and calls a function called `refreshChart()`. This function takes the value and adds it to the original values on the fly before re-drawing the chart:

```
function refreshChart() {
    var balance1 = document.getElementById('balance1').value;
    var balance2 = document.getElementById('balance2').value;
    if(!balance1) {
        balance1 = 0;
    }
    if(!balance2) {
        balance2 = 0;
    }
    for(var i = 0, length = table.rows.length; i < length; i++) {
        table.rows[i].c['1'].v = parseFloat(table.rows[i].c['2'].v) + parseFloat(balance1) + parseFloat(balance2);
    }
    drawChart();
    return false;
}
```

It takes the balance entered and adds it to the original value stored in `table.rows[i].c['2'].v` and overwrites the value in `table.rows[i].c['1'].v` which is used by the chart. It then calls the original `drawChart()` function but the new data is used.

I played around with some default data and this is the output I tested it with on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NPgp5/2/).

Comment: Thanks, that's great.  I have marked the question as answered. In a slight variation to the method above, I have been trying in various ways to get the sum of two inputs and pass this to the Google Chart (instead of one), without success.  Would you be able to amend your answer so that it would work with two inputs?  Thanks, Nick

Comment: @Nick, sure, I've updated the answer and the JSFiddle to take two inputs... it just ads them together and updates the graph with that value.